# what is practical use of System.Transactions?

Tags: .net, transactions, transactionscope, system.transactions

I have seen [System.Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.aspx) namespace, and wondered, can I actually make a RDMBS with this namespace usage?

But when I saw some examples, I do not understand how System.Transactions does anything beyond simple try catch and getting us success/failure result?

This is the example on MSDN's website, I know it may be very simple but I am unable to understand the benefit in this sample, can someone tell me what is difference between simple try/catch and Transaction scope in this following sample.

If I am supposed to make a RDBMS (create my own RDMBS), I understand we have to write lots of logs to disk of the operations we execute and at the end we undo those operations in the case of rollback, but here there is nothing about undoing anything.

```
// This function takes arguments for 2 connection strings and commands to create a transaction 
// involving two SQL Servers. It returns a value > 0 if the transaction is committed, 0 if the 
// transaction is rolled back. To test this code, you can connect to two different databases 
// on the same server by altering the connection string, or to another 3rd party RDBMS by 
// altering the code in the connection2 code block.
static public int CreateTransactionScope(
    string connectString1, string connectString2,
    string commandText1, string commandText2)
{
    // Initialize the return value to zero and create a StringWriter to display results.
    int returnValue = 0;
    System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();

    try
    {
        // Create the TransactionScope to execute the commands, guaranteeing
        // that both commands can commit or roll back as a single unit of work.
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectString1))
            {
                // Opening the connection automatically enlists it in the 
                // TransactionScope as a lightweight transaction.
                connection1.Open();

                // Create the SqlCommand object and execute the first command.
                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(commandText1, connection1);
                returnValue = command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command1: {0}", returnValue);

                // If you get here, this means that command1 succeeded. By nesting
                // the using block for connection2 inside that of connection1, you
                // conserve server and network resources as connection2 is opened
                // only when there is a chance that the transaction can commit.   
                using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(connectString2))
                {
                    // The transaction is escalated to a full distributed
                    // transaction when connection2 is opened.
                    connection2.Open();

                    // Execute the second command in the second database.
                    returnValue = 0;
                    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(commandText2, connection2);
                    returnValue = command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command2: {0}", returnValue);
                }
            }

            // The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown,
            // Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.
            scope.Complete();

        }

    }
    catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("TransactionAbortedException Message: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    catch (ApplicationException ex)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("ApplicationException Message: {0}", ex.Message);
    }

    // Display messages.
    Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());

    return returnValue;
}
```

In above example what are we committing? I guess SQL Client library will do everything right? Does this mean that System.IO.StringWriter will either contain all success text or all failure text? or is there any locking between scope of TransactionScope?

Comment: What do you mean by "make a RDBMS" ?

Comment: Relational Database Management System, copy of SQL Server or MySQL or Oracle, I mean if I want to make my own XYZSql database system on .net, then can I use this?

Comment: Not really, but you'd could implement support for System.Transactions in your .NET XYZSql ADO.NET driver if your new XYZSql database system supports transactions.

Comment: @nos, Thanks, well now I dont find any help on how to implement System.Transactions, I have looked all MSDN, thanks for your comment.

Comment: +1 - I'd like to understand how to implement transaction support using this namespace - not necessarily a RDBMS, it seems like there could be other simpler applications that could make use of transactions.

Comment: @Kragen, yes I also intend to do the same, I just gave it as an example of RDBMS, yes it can be used at many places.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494550/how-does-transactionscope-roll-back-transactions/494596#494596) might help. >The TransactionScope class works with the Transaction class, which is thread-specific. When the TransactionScope is created, it checks to see if there is a Transaction for the thread and it can use an existing transaction (it might call for a new one regardless) then it uses that, otherwise, it creates a new one and pushes it onto the stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all TransactionScope is not the same as try/catch. TransactionScope is by the name scope of a transaction. Transaction in scope has to be explicitly commited by calling Complete on the scope. Any other case (including exception raised in scope) results in finishing using block which disposes the scope and implicitly rollback the incomplete transaction but it will not handle the exception.

In basic scenarios transaction from System.Transactions behaves same as db client transaction. System.Transactions provides following additional features:

- API agnostic. You can use same transaction scope for oracle, sql server or web service. This is important when your transaction is started in layer which is persistance ignorant (doesn't know any information about persistance implementation).
- Automatic enlistment. If specified on connection string (default behavior). New database connection automatically enlists into existing transaction.
- Automatic promotion to distributed transaction. When second connection enlists to transaction it will be automatically promoted to distirbuted one (MSDTC is needed). Promotion also works when you enlist other coordinated resource like transactional web service.
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

A Transaction will do the necessary locking for you. Also, there is an implicit Rollback, when the transaction is Disposed at the end of its scope if it was not committed by Complete() (as suggested by the comments). So in case there is an exception, all operations are rolled back automatically and no change will take place in the database. For instance, if the second query fails, it will also make the changes of the first query to be discarded.

However for the StringWriter, it will still contain messages up to the point of failure (for example

```
Rows to be affected by command1: {0}
ApplicationException Message: {0}
```

can both appear in your log after this code.

As for creating an RDBMS with this class, I'm not really sure I understand your question. If you want to actually create a relational dabase management system, I would say you are probably looking at the wrong place. If you mean you want to access an RDBMS via Transaction, I would say, it depends on your needs, ie. if you need Transactions that can guarantee that your statements will run in order and in an all-or-none fashion, then yes, Transaction is a good place to start.

Comment: Yes, I intent to create RDBMS, not use one, I know I can use database client library transaction such as SqlTransaction etc. But I still dont understand what do you mean by necessary locking since, I see it this way that even if I dont use TransactionScope here, I will still get the same result in case of any of commands will fail right?

Comment: Sorry to bother again, do you mean that System.Transactions will implicitly undo the changes made to Sql database even if I have not used SqlTransaction explicitly in this code? This means that Sql Client Library will automatically create an instance of SqlTransaction and use it, so practically there is no use of System.Transactions when I can directly use SqlTransaction?

Comment: TransactionScope is an abtraction over SqlTransaction, and it can span other things than an SqlTransaction, e,g, an MSMQ transaction.

Comment: No you will not get the same result, if query1 is successful, but query2 fails without the transaction, query1 will still change the db. Implicit undo means that if you don't call Complete() it will undo the operations when the scope ends. As for creating an RDBMS, I recommend you look at some open-source databases first (I recommend postgreSQL), but in general I would advise against a project like that unless you have a lot of resources.