# Which is the best method in transactional system? using TransactionScope in Business Layer or inside Database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, transactions

which is the best method in transactional system? using TransactionScope in Business Layer or inside Database?

I am using SQL Server 2008 and C3 with Framework 4.0

Inside Business Layer like:

```
 using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
 {
    ...
    scope.Complete();
 }
```

Or inside Database like:

```
Begin tran InsertTrace
Begin try
...
End try
Begin Catch
    Rollback tran InsertTrace
    ...
End Catch
```

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382892/database-begintransaction-vs-transactions-transactionscope

Comment: your example use Database.BeginTransaction() inside cose i think, I am asking inside database as T-SQL or in bussiness layer

Comment: This might help but not sure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701934/transactionscope-and-transactions