# Transaction Scope not working for multiple operations in .net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, transactions

I have multiple operations in the DoWork() Method, where i'm using the transaction scope,but it is not working as expected.

Whenever there is a failure in DataInsert2(), it should revert both DataInsert1() and DataInsert2(). But currently it is reverting only DataInsert2()..?

Let me know if i'm doing any mistakes here.

**//DoWork()**

```
public void DoWork()
            {
                try
                {

                  TransactionOptions tranOptions = UtilityBL.GetTransOptions();
                    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, tranOptions))
                    {
                        if (DataInsert1())
                        {
                          DataInsert2() ;
                        }
                        scope.Complete();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Info(string.Format(UploadMessages.FailedMsg));
                   if (ContextUtil.IsInTransaction)
                        ContextUtil.SetAbort();
                }
          }
```

**//DataInsert1**

```
public bool DataInsert1()
        {
           bool fileUploadStatus=false;
           try
            {

                DAL.InsertDetails1() 
                fileUploadStatus=true;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info(string.Format(UploadMessages.FailedMsg));
           }
            return fileUploadStatus;
        }
```

**//DataInsert2**

```
public bool DataInsert2()
        {
           try
            { 
                DAL.InsertDetails2() 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info(string.Format(UploadMessages.FailedMsg));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Without knowing what's in `DAL`, it's not possible to tell why this might not work. In particular, `TransactionScope` itself doesn't really do anything, code running inside it must be transaction-aware and opt in. This may not happen if (for example) it spans new threads to do work, or if the work you're doing doesn't actually support transactions.

Comment: Looks like you're relying on an exception to be caught in `DoWork()` to roll back your transaction but in the data insert methods you are swallowing them.

Comment: @ChrisPickford I tried by adding transaction abort() in data insert catch blocks as well. But still the same issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494550/how-does-transactionscope-roll-back-transactions you do not need explicit rollback, so you can even put thy try-catch block outside the transaction scope. It works out of box and you need just Complete().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simplify your code as follows. Your `DataInsert` methods are swallowing any exceptions thrown by the `DAL.InsertDetails` methods.

```
public void DoWork()
{
  TransactionOptions tranOptions = UtilityBL.GetTransOptions();
  using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, tranOptions))
  {
    try {
      DAL.InsertDetails1();
      DAL.InsertDetails2();
      scope.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Info(string.Format(UploadMessages.FailedMsg));

        if (ContextUtil.IsInTransaction)
          ContextUtil.SetAbort();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me try this.