# Transaction across DAL operations + a web service call + logging

Tags: c#, transactions, data-access-layer

[I've already looked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493649/transactions-across-several-dal-methods-from-the-one-method-in-the-bll) and found some great advice on managing transactions.

My problem is that I'm also calling a web service in at least one case, logging to a database table. Here's some psuedo-code that might help make things more clear:

```
customer = batchRefundToProcess.RefundCustomer;

                //Validate everything
                if (ValidateRefund(batchRefundToProcess) == false)
                {
                    refund.RefundStatusId = (int)REFUNDSTATUSES.RefundDenied;
                    refund.ReviewedBy = displayUserName;
                    refund.Update();
                    return false;
                }

                //get this customer's payments
                List<RefundTran> trans = customer.ARTransactions;

                refund.RefundStatusId = (int)REFUNDSTATUSES.RefundInProcess;
                refund.ReviewDate = DateTime.Now;
                refund.ReviewedBy = displayUserName;
                refund.Update();

                List<RefundTran> paperTransactions = new List<RefundTran>();


                foreach (RefundTran transaction in trans)
                {

                    if (customer.Balance < 0) //balance is negative if we owe them money
                    {

                        //processtransaction has the following side effects:
                        //1. refund detail is created for the tran
                        //2. customer is billed for the refunded amount, web service is called

                        var paperTransaction = processTransaction(customer, transaction, refund);
                        if (paperTransaction != null) //this transaction qualifies for a paper check for one reason or another
                        {
                            paperTransactions.Add(paperTransaction);
                        }
                    }


                }
                //get total amount
                //basically, the sum total of all their paper check transactions plus whatever's left on their balance, if anything
                decimal paperCheckAmount = paperTransactions.Sum(pt => pt.Amount) - customer.Balance;
                if (paperTransactions.Count > 0)
                {
                    //cut a check for all the transactions together
                    AddLineToFile(customer, paperCheckAmount, paperTransactions.First(), REFUNDFILETYPE.ElectronicCheck, refund.RefundId);

                }

                refund.RefundStatusId = (int)REFUNDSTATUSES.RefundApproved;
                refund.ReviewedBy = displayUserName;
                refund.Update();
            } //end using block
            return true;
```

There are webservice calls in there, and some database logging. I know there's no magic way to "undo" a webservice call to an outside vendor, but how do I keep the database logging from rolling back along with the transaction if it fails? What should I do in the event that I've already made the webservice call? Am I making this too hard? I don't want to bill a customer and then fail on cutting them a check, or worse (in my organization's opinion), cut them a check but fail on billing their account!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but the only way you would achieve something like this is using something like NServiceBus.

Have a look at http://andreasohlund.net/2009/08/24/achieving-consistency-using-nservicebus/
it provides an example of a similar requirement